# Review process for comments on an article

Tags: peer-review, ethics, paper-submission

Recently I have submitted comments on a article to Elsevier journal. These comments include rectification and proper implementation of certain technique. The editor of journal told me that, they will first send my comments to author of article for response and after that my comments will be sent for review.

> Now my query is, why and for what purpose they are seeking response from author of paper ? Although I have no problem with that but I am curious to know,  how that author would responds to my comments on his/her paper ?

PS. I have checked similar question [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/51813/receiving-comments-on-ones-article) but I find this question not so useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The procedure is quite common, and frequently comments and response to comments, if significant, are then published together.

> Now my query is, why and for what purpose they are seeking response from author of paper ?

Why shouldn't they? You are actually criticizing their work, highlighting some flaws. You might be right, you might have misinterpreted their paper, or you might be plainly wrong: whatever the case, it's fair to allow the authors to reply to your criticisms and explain their point of view, if different.

> Although I have no problem with that but I am curious to know, how that author would responds to my comments on his/her paper ?

Well, there's no general answer for this: it depends on the kind of comments. Sometimes they might simply acknowledge the issues, whereas sometimes the authors write another commentary explaining why they think the comments are wrong. And sometimes the two parties reach a common point of view.

Comment: What if the author do not respond to editor?

Comment: Also for [APS](https://journals.aps.org/prb/authors/comments-physical-review-b) is is the same procedure. Since you have criticized their work, it is natural to give the comments to someone who has spend high amount of time only on that paper, so the authors and the previous referees seems to be the best option.

Comment: @IgotiT I think it's an unlikely event that one, but the journal will probably have a procedure to handle the case. Which procedure depends on the journal.